# Reactive form an array of other reactive forms

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

I am trying to create a reactive form and below is a prototype of it.

[image]

I have to create 3 reactive forms **Form1, Form2, Form3** and then club them into single reactive form say **SignUpForm**. It's like **SignUpForm** is an array of 3 different reactive forms. I Googled FormBuilder, FormArray and FormGroup but got all confused.

Comment: I still don't have minimum reputation to use embedded images in the post. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Check my repository, i am new in Angular but i created a reactive form with second levels to formGroup - https://github.com/Cuchu/dynamic-reactive-form

Answer (score 1):

Create each of the three forms - Form1, Form2 and Form3 using FormBuilder:

```
form1group = this._formBuilder.group({
// Your formControls go here
})
```

Then create a SignUpForm containing these three formgroups (form1group, form2group and form3group).

```
signupForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    form1group,
    form2group,
    form3group
})
```

FormArray is an array of FormControls you should use when dealing with dynamic forms (i.e. when new FormControls are required to be added to form dynamically).

Comment: Please tell how to access this form in HTML.

Comment: Use this: signupForm.get('form1group').controls as FormArray

Answer (score 1):

you should use FormArray,First, on top of your other form imports, you’ll want to import FormArray from the Angular forms module:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
signUpForm: FormGroup;
items: FormArray ;

ngOnInit() {
  this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    formName: '',
    formDescription: '',
    items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
  });
   this.addItem()
   this.addItem();
}

createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    field1: '',
    field2: ''
  });
}

addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.signUpForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}
```

in **html:**

```
<div formArrayName="items"
  *ngFor="let item of signUpForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="field1" placeholder="field1">
    <input formControlName="field2" placeholder="field1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it’s as simple as calling our `addItem` method in our template when the user clicks to add a new item or do it in our component.

Comment: Great. this helped.

Comment: @PranjalSuccessena your welcome, i made some changes i couldn't try the code myself if there was any problem notify me :)